# How do I apply a specific class to a navigation list, without breaking the nav functionality in mobile-view?

Tags: html, css, list, navigation, html-lists

I'm trying to use the following responsive navigation: http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/dqnKv

```
/*Border surrounding entire navigation - NAV CONTAINER*/
.navborder {
border-top: 10px solid #6e6f1f;
border-right: 20px solid #6e6f1f;
border-bottom: 10px solid #6e6f1f;
border-left: 20px solid #6e6f1f;
background: #6e6f1f; 
}

/*Last nav li padding appears*/
    .last {
    padding-right:14px;
    }

/*White bg & top spacing btwn nav*/
    #site-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    width: 100%;
    }

@media screen and (max-width : 1240px){
    /*Border disappears*/
    #site-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    }
}

/*Slider element*/
.slidebehind {
margin-top:-60px;
}


@media screen and (max-width : 768px){
    /*Slider element jumps down - keep it above nav*/
    .slidebehind {
    margin-top:-40px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width : 762px){
    /*Border disappears*/
    .navborder {
    border: none;
    }
    /*Logo disappears*/
    li img {
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    /*Last nav li padding disappears*/
    .last {
    padding-right:0px;
    }
    /*Slider element jumps down - keep it above nav*/
    .slidebehind {
    margin-top:-106px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width : 1200px){
    /*UCR Logo margin - come inward*/
    .ucrlogo {
    margin-right:20px;
    }
    /*Breadcrumbs margin - come inward*/
    .breadcrumb {
    margin-left:20px;
    }
}

/*Menu shrinks*/
@media screen and (max-width : 1200px){
    /*Border disappears*/
    #menu {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
}



/* BEGIN NAV STYLES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul.navlist {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99999;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    padding-right: 18px; padding-left:18px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-Cn18', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #6e6f1f;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .99; 
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #6e6f1f;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f5f1e6;
    color: #6e6f1f;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #6e6f1f;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #6e6f1f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
    border: 10px solid #6e6f1f;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: .99; 
}

.show-menu:hover {
    background: #898a2c;
    border: 10px solid #898a2c;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 762px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

However, I want the nav list to have a specific name, to differentiate its styles from other list styles.

I've tried using something this: `ul.navlist {nav css here}` (shown in the codepen link)

and applied it to my html `<ul class="navlist">`, but for some reason, this breaks the navigation when resizing below 762px.

How do I apply a unique name to the nav list ul, without "breaking it" when resizing to small screens?

(You can see what I mean if you view the codepen, and see how the nav becomes "broken" after resizing to mobile view. If you remove the .navlist class, you'll see that it works fine, but has no class).

---

*UPDATE - 7/29/14*

Let me explain this a different way; I can see how my wording was confusing.

**This is the EXACT menu I'm trying to achieve:
http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/GFDou**

Here's the original CSS:

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

**And here is the menu I have (after adding a class, navlist, to the ul):
http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/dqnKv**

Here's the CSS with class added:

```
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul.navlist {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

I'm trying to give a specific class name to the navigation ul.

For some reason, when I do this, it "breaks" the mobile-view of the navigation.

I don't know how else to explain when something "breaks", except to say that it's not working the way it *should* work (it *should* work like the first link).

See how in the first link, when switching to smaller/mobile view, the navigation doesn't look the same as the second? The only difference is the second one has a class added to the ul, but it's "breaking" the original style/functionality of the smaller navigation. How to I add a class to the ul without "breaking" the original style/functionality?

Hopefully that clears things up. :(

Comment: When you say break, what do you mean? applying css or id when resize can only be done using javascript

Comment: Given the same element, an id will override a class in priorities.  This may be the reason that the list is breaking.  If you'd like to distinguish the list from other styles without breaking it, I'd suggest using a new class instead of id.

Comment: You can view the codepen to see what I mean by "break". If you remove the class, you can view it "unbroken".

Comment: @LorenPosen thank you for the suggestion. I used a class instead of an id, and it does work for the desktop-sized navigation. But the mobile-sized nav is what's not working properly.

Comment: I think we may still be a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish. You should try to reword the question and be more specific about what specifically is "breaking."

Comment: Please see update for further explanation - I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, a hover menu only works on non-touch devices, so this menu may work on IOS by clicking and double clicking on Android, I'm guessing since :hover is not something I use on menus for about 2 years now.

**I've assumed you're hiding sub menus on smaller viewports and that the top levels are links.**

I've cleaned this up based on best guesses, you'll need to learn by it. Read the information below this code chunk. Anything shared by ALL viewports is outside a media query, styles only affecting larger viewports are inside a min-width, stuff that's only max-width (smaller viewports) and not shared between all sizes is inside a max-width.

**http://jsbin.com/wafuso/1/edit**

**http://jsbin.com/wafuso/1/**

Here's one with the hover on smaller viewports and other adjustments:

http://jsbin.com/roway/1/edit

This is to learn by.

```
.navlist,
.navlist * {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navlist li a {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStd-Cn18', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #6e6f1f;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .99;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

@media (min-width:763px) { 
    ul.navlist {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99999;
    }

    .navlist li { float: left }

    .navlist li:hover ul a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #6e6f1f;
    }

    .navlist li > a { padding: 0 18px }

    .navlist li li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        height: auto;
        line-height: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        min-width: 100px;
        padding: 10px 18px;
    }

    .navlist li ul {
        display: none;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .navlist li ul li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*Prevent text wrapping*/


    .navlist li a:hover + .hidden,
    .navlist .hidden:hover { display: block }

    /*Hover state for top level links*/

    .navlist li:hover a {
        background: #fff;
        color: #6e6f1f;
    }

    .navlist li:hover ul a {
        background: #f5f1e6;
        color: #6e6f1f;
    }
}


.show-menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #6e6f1f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
    border: 10px solid #6e6f1f;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: .99;
}

.show-menu:hover {
    background: #898a2c;
    border: 10px solid #898a2c;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width:762px) { 
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu { display: block }

    .navlist {
        position: static;
        display: none;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .show-menu { display: block }


    .disappear { display: none }
}
```

---

What you have here is general selectors like:

```
ul {styles}
```

and

```
ul li {styles}
```

which will affect every ul and li in the entire site.

If you add a class to a ul, you would then refer to it in the css as:

```
.navlist {toplevel style on the ul}

.navlist li {more styles for the lists}
```

and so forth

Also, if you don't want something to affect other viewport widths, such as everything above 700px is one style and everything under is another, you use min-width and stack in the order of smallest to largest, so if you want the font size at 700px to be 20px but it's 30px at 1200px and up, but the base (the small viewport) is 15px it would be like this:

```
.myselector {font-size:15px;}

@media (min-width:700px) {
  .myselector {font-size:20px;}
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .myselector {font-size:30px;}
}
```

Max-width media queries stack in the reverse, where the smallest is last. Please read up on responsive design further.

Comment: The third link you provided is exactly what I needed - thank you! :)